# Erase all cookies in NSURLSession iOS

Tags: nsurlsession

How can I erase all cookies from the NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage? The only methods I am aware of delete a single specified cookie, however, the cookies are handled behind the scenes by NSURLSession. (Programming in Swift)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
let cookieStore = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in cookieStore.cookies ?? [] {
    cookieStore.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
```

Comment: Why this code is not generating crash for modifying collection while iterating it? Just want a confirmation on it.

Comment: @FauadAnwar Arrays in Swift are structs and thus value types, so they get copied rather than referenced.

Answer (score 17):

This achieves the same result as the other answers but with one line of code:

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies?.forEach(HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie)
```

Answer (score 9):

Similarly, for swift 3.0+, xCode 8.0+

```
let cookieStore = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
for cookie in cookieStore.cookies ?? [] {
    cookieStore.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
```